# JS:Specific weight chart

Tags: javascript, ajax

Firstly to understand my issue you should see the pricture in the link below :

http://www.hostfile.nl/fpimages/03bkr5tq46/16043/screenshot.jpeg.html

The idea and my issue is to create a chart of weight such as the picture or the site http://www.loseit.com/#Goals , the description is like this :

1- the chart contain two lines : 1 - Record Today's Weight , 2- My goal weight.

2- so I can record everyday my today's weight and when I click "record" button directly I see  new line is added in chart in the space of today (you can see the picture )

what I need is an example or code of chart do almost the same fonctionality,really I'm not professional in javascript code?

Comment: Google for something like "add point to line chart"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Flot](http://www.flotcharts.org/) (JavaScript library for jQuery to generate charts)

```
// a null signifies separate line segments
var myData = [[0, 12], [7, 12], null, [7, 2.5], [12, 2.5]];
var myGoal = [[0, 20], [12, 20]]

$.plot($("#myChart"), [ myData, myGoal ]);
```

check out this example : https://refork.codicode.com/xa2e